# HTTP sources with h5ai appear empty in XBMC

Tags: apache, xbmc

I'm having some trouble adding a custom source to my XBMC set up. I've got an Apache2 server up and running that I use to stream movies to my computer and would like to include it as a source in XBMC. I'm no web server expert, but I managed to get h5ai style indexing on my server, which I'd like to keep. The problem is that when h5ai is enabled, XBMC can't locate any of the files. With h5ai disabled I have no issue browsing through my files.

The obvious solution is to keep h5ai off, but since I use my server outside of XBMC, I'd like to find a way to keep it on. I'm very new when it comes to web servers, so it's very possible I'm just doing something wrong. I merely followed the instructions of placing the _h5ai folder in my path and editing .htaccess. If anyone could shed some light on the issue (solution or simply an explanation) I would greatly appreciate it.

Additional info: I'm running XBMC 12.0. My server is a rented seedbox, so I have no root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is making a subdirectory specifically for XBMC and adding a .htaccess file that keeps h5ai indexing out of it:

```
DirectoryIndex  index.html
```

Then have the HTTP source include the full path to said subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by removing "IndexOptions         IconsAreLinks" from .htaccess